# Certification validation issues with ppa

Tags: ppa

So I just installed ubuntu on my computer at work and when I try to add a ppa I get the following message:

```
Cannot add PPA: '"Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa: (60, 'server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none')"'.
```

I have tried various things that I have found in other forums but haven't had any success. Some of the things I have tried:

setting the time

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

I have tried adding the following ppas:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Any idea why I am getting the error and how to fix it?

Comment: Is it possible that at work you access the internet via a proxy? Perhaps the HTTPS connection failed.

Comment: If you are unsure: can you add the results of `set | grep -i proxy`?

Comment: Turns out my work has a special certificate I need to install.

Comment: @CodesLikeA_Mokey So did the problem go away?

Comment: Yes, once I installed the certificate the problem was resolved.